# How to calculate days between two dates in ios. in between two dates

Tags: ios

my question is to calculate days between two different dates in iOS.
to calculate how many days between two dates. i have to calculate 1990/02/05 to today date
how many days in between.

Comment: [Link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575689/objective-c-calculating-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates) and [Link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236719/number-of-days-between-two-nsdate-objects) [Link 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739483/number-of-days-between-two-nsdates)

Comment: [The easiest of all](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=cocoa+number+of+days+between+two+dates&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=vA57U8bBK4vC8gfzxYDICA)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 NSString *start = @"2010-09-01";
NSString *end = @"2010-12-01";

NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *startDate = [f dateFromString:start];
NSDate *endDate = [f dateFromString:end];

NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                fromDate:startDate
                                                  toDate:endDate
                                                 options:0];
NSLog(@"%ld", [components day]);
```

Comment: thank you sir for giving me such a valuable answer