# finding out days remain from array of dates

Tags: iphone, ios, date, calendar

i have one array something like below

```
_combinedBirthdates(
"03/12/2013",
"03/12/2013",
"08/13/1990",
"12/09/1989",
"02/06",
"09/08",
"03/02/1990",
"08/22/1989",
"03/02",
"05/13",
"10/16",
"07/08",
"08/31/1990",
"04/14/1992",
"12/15/1905",
"08/14/1989",
"10/07/1987",
"07/25",
"07/17/1989",
"03/24/1987",
"07/28/1988",
"01/21/1990",
"10/13"
```

)

this all are NSString

i am trying to make new array from this which contains days remaining something like below

(days remaining for particular birthdate)
(we will compair current date with above date array and we will find out remaining days)
      _newarray(
       "125",
       "100",
       "65",
       and till end like this..
       )

i am using below code for this

```
unsigned int unitFlags =  NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSCalendar *currCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                            initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];


NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSLog(@" currCalendar%@",currCalendar);

NSMutableArray * _newarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString * str in _combinedBirthdates){

    NSDate * toDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str];
    NSDateComponents *daysInfo = [currCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:[NSDate date]  toDate:toDate  options:0];
    int days = [daysInfo day];
    [_newarray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",days]];
}
NSLog(@" _newarray%@",_newarray);
```

and this is what i am getting as output when i print _newarray plz help me thank you

```
_newlymadeArray(
"-1",
"-1",
"-8248",
"-8495",
"-4454",
"-4454",
"-8412",
"-8604",
"-4454",
"-4454",
"-4454",
"-4454",
"-8230",
"-7638",
"-39170",
"-8612",
"-9289",
"-4454",
"-8640",
"-9486",
"-8994",
"-8452",
"-4454",
"-2072",
"-888",
"-8315"
)
```

Comment: i can't get wt u actually want :(

Comment: days remaning for paticular birthdate

Comment: i think this is solved in this question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358210/how-to-make-another-array-containing-number-of-days-remain`

Comment: Clarification needed on the requirement, i.e., you have given some dates, but with which date these dates needs to compare?

Comment: Also the question and the code is entirely different. You need the number of days remaining for the birthday. But your code calculates the number of days passed from the actual birthdate. (means 13/02/2013-20/08/1990 )

Comment: so suggest something Midhun MP as you know whats wrong im doing how to find just remaining days ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use this.I think this one may help you.

```
NSDateFormatter *tempFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [tempFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

    NSString *str = [tempFormatter stringFromDate:@"yourStartDate"];
    NSDate *startdate = [tempFormatter dateFromString:str];

    str = [tempFormatter stringFromDate:@"yourEndDate"];
    NSDate *endDate = [tempFormatter dateFromString:str];

    int i = [startdate timeIntervalSince1970];
    int j = [toDate timeIntervalSince1970];

    double X = j-i;

    int days=(int)((double)X/(3600.0*24.00));
```

Comment: when i try to print int days then this is what i get Single stepping until exit from function objc_msgSend, 
which has no line number information.

Comment: thank you very much i got answer from ur style

Comment: Your most welcome dear...

Answer (score 0):

use below code to compare two dates pass both date in same format

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateformat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSString *StrDate1 = [dateformat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSString *StrDate2 = [dateformat stringFromDate:date2];
NSDate *firstDate = [dateformat dateFromString:StrDate1];
NSDate *secondDate = [dateformat dateFromString:StrDate2];
NSTimeInterval lastDiff = [firstDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
NSTimeInterval todaysDiff = [secondDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
NSTimeInterval dateDiff = todaysDiff - lastDiff;
int day = dateDiff/(3600*24);

 // days are remaining
```

use this in for loop you will gate remaining days

Comment: when i try to prinkt int day then this is what i get Single stepping until exit from function objc_msgSend, 
which has no line number information.

Comment: thank you very much i got answer by ur style