# Incrementing a date's year by one if that date has already passed

Tags: iphone, ios, date

I have an array containing birth dates like the one below:

```
 Array(
"11/07/2013",
"07/10/2013",
"20/02/2013"
)
```

Now I want to make a new array based on whether or not the date has passed. Writing this question in 2013, if a current date has passed then we will change that date's year to 2014. If it hasn't passed then we will have it stay the 2013 date.

For example:

```
NewArray(
 "11/07/2013",    no change cus this date hasnt passed yet
 "07/10/2013",     no change same as above
 "20/02/2014"     **as date has already passed thats why 2014**
```

I'm using the following code for this

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSString *curYear = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSString *nextYear = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", ([curYear intValue] + 1)];
for(int i = 0; i < [_newlymadeArray count]; i++)
{
    NSString *dateStr = [_newlymadeArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSComparisonResult comResult = [[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr] compare:    [NSDate date]];
    if(comResult == NSOrderedAscending)
    {
        [dateStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:curYear withString:nextYear];
        [_newlymadeArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:dateStr];
         NSLog(@"_newlymadeArray%@",_newlymadeArray);
    }
NSLog(@"_newlymadeArray%@",_newlymadeArray);
```

This is however what I get when I NSLog `_newlymadeArray`:

```
 after replacing (
 "11/07/2013",
 "07/10/2013",
 "20/02/2013"       
 )
```

At index 2 **it should be "20/02/2014"** instead of the 2013 date. What might cause my problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: hey you can use my code which i have give in your previous Question 

if date < 0 then change year

Comment: Perhaps the [Calendrical Calculations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW1) section of the Apple [Date and Time Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039-SW1) will be of help to you.

Comment: Check the datre with NSOrderedAscending and NSOrdereddescending and make change

Comment: there are 4 answer non of them is your Pratik can you plz give me answer here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377466/finding-out-days-remain-from-array-of-dates/15377946#15377946

look second answer

Comment: thats was for finding difference thats totally other story pratik thats solved please read this question again by the way you really helped me there hope to see help form you here too :)

Comment: in this you have to put just if condition.

Comment: Why aren't you holding an array of `NSDate` objects?  This is a more appropriate why of holding this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made some modifications to your code, and it is working as you want.

In my code I've compared date, which is in Ascending form of current date. If it satisfies the condition, then I've fetched YEAR from matched date, by the DateFormatter "yyyy". Then I simply increment this year by 1, and replace this year in old Date, which is "20/02/**2013**" to "20/02/**2014**"

```
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"11/07/2013",@"07/10/2013",@"20/02/2013", nil];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
for(int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++)
{
    NSString *dateStr = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    NSComparisonResult comResult = [[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr] compare:    [NSDate date]];
    if(comResult == NSOrderedAscending)
    {
        NSDateFormatter *yrFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [yrFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
        NSString *curYear = [yrFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
        NSString *nextYear = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", ([curYear intValue] + 1)];

        NSLog(@"%@",curYear);
        NSLog(@"%@",nextYear);

        dateStr = [dateStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:curYear withString:nextYear];
        NSLog(@"%@",dateStr);
        [array replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:dateStr];
        NSLog(@"_newlymadeArray%@",array);
    }
    NSLog(@"_newlymadeArray%@",array);
}
```

This seems to be working perfectly, so I hope it helps you.

Comment: damn man you are expert man tell me when you started to learn objective c? tell me how long its been?

Comment: thanx man, bt m not that much expert. trying to improve knowledge day by day. i  am workin on iOS since 7 months only. @DesaiPrakash

Comment: @Dhruvik Just a small request: instead of just posting a block of code, could you add a small clarification on what the problem was and how you solved it? It would certainly improve your answer.

Comment: @Bart sure dude., i've added some explanations in my answer. plz go through it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Plese dear try to use this one.I think this one may help

```
 NSCalendar*       calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    components.year = 1;
    NSDate* newDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents: components toDate:@"YourDate" options: 0];
```

Otherwise you can use this one code.

```
   if (comResult == NSOrderedSame)
   {
       NSCalendar*       calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    components.year = 1;

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"11/07/2013"];

    NSDate* newDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents: components toDate:date options: 0];
   // here replace your array object with this "newDate"

   }
```

Comment: Dharmbir i cant understand it as im so new. can you tell where its comparing my array dates with current date?

Comment: please prakash i've change my code according to you.So please try to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Compare your array date to today's date with `NSDate compare` function. Here are the details:

```
NSString *arrayDateString = @"20/02/2013" // fetch this string from your array
NSDate *todaysDate = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSDate* d = [df dateFromString:arrayDateString];

// now compare this date (d) with todaysDate using NSDate function
if ([d compare:todaysdate]== NSOrderedAscending)  
{//write your code here}
```

If it results `NSOrderedAscending`, then it means array date is earlier than today's date.

So for that date, update year incremented by one using `NSDateComponents`:

```
NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
dayComponent.year = 1;

NSCalendar *theCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
dateToBeIncremented = [theCalendar dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:dateToBeIncremented options:0];
```

Or you can use `NSDate` function itself:

```
NSDate *now = arrayDate;
int yearsToAdd = 1;
NSDate *newDate1 = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*365*year];
```

But second option is not full-proof - because of leap year problem.

Hope this two options help you, for solving your issue.

Comment: i cant understand it as im so new. can you tell where its comparing my array dates with current date?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray * array = [[NSArray alloc]   initWithObjects:@"11/07/2013",@"07/10/2013",@"20/02/2013", nil];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *output = [NSMutableArray new];

for(int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++)
{
    NSString *dateStr = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];
    if ([date compare:now] == NSOrderedAscending)
    {

        [components setYear:1];
        date = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:date options:0];

    }
    dateStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    [output addObject:dateStr];

}
NSLog(@"Result : %@",output);
```